# Permission denied; , neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns

Tags: linux

I have a code that uses `ncrcat` to extract values from several `.nc` files. In a loop, I ask this code to extract from one file at a time. The names of these files are stored in a text file. It seems that since these files are stored in a different directory, the code has trouble reading it in, even if I add the path.
Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

outputNumber="$(wc -l Time122009.txt)"  #"$(ls -lq *_??????.nc | wc -l)"

echo "the number of lines in the Time text file is ${outputNumber}"

# from all the netcdf files extract the vel_u (and eventually vel_v) with the indices that are in I.txt and J.txt
for ((index=1; index<=10; index++)) #for now only 10 loops were done, the 10 should eventually be replaced by outputNumber 
do
arrI1=$(sed -n $index'p' I1.txt)
arrI2=$(sed -n $index'p' I2.txt)

arrJ1=$(sed -n $index'p' J1.txt)
arrJ2=$(sed -n $index'p' J2.txt)

Addition=`expr $index + 253` #I want it to start reading file Time122009.txt at position 253
Time=$(sed -n $Addition'p' Time122009.txt)

        ncrcat -C -F -d nj_u,${arrJ1},${arrJ2} -d ni_u,${arrI1},${arrI2} -v vel_u $(../GRAPHIQUES/${Time}) $index.nc #extract from variable vel_u in dimensions nj_u and ni_u from file found in Time

done
```

The first values of I.txt and J.txt look like this:

```
5.2000000e+02
5.1000000e+02
4.9800000e+02
4.9200000e+02
4.8600000e+02
4.8000000e+02
4.7600000e+02
```

And Time122009.txt looks like this

```
20091207_142???.nc
20091207_143???.nc
20091207_144???.nc
20091207_150???.nc
20091207_152???.nc
20091207_153???.nc
20091207_154???.nc
```

This is the output:

```
the number of lines in the Time text file is 378 Time122009.txt
    ./geknoei.sh: line 30: ../GRAPHIQUES/20091209_080725.nc: Permission denied
    , neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
    ./geknoei.sh: line 30: ../GRAPHIQUES/20091209_082632.nc: Permission denied
    , neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
    ./geknoei.sh: line 30: ../GRAPHIQUES/20091209_083???.nc: No such file or directory
    , neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
    ./geknoei.sh: line 30: ../GRAPHIQUES/20091209_084604.nc: Permission denied
    , neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
    ./geknoei.sh: line 30: ../GRAPHIQUES/20091209_090511.nc: Permission denied
    , neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
    ./geknoei.sh: line 30: ../GRAPHIQUES/20091209_092443.nc: Permission denied
    , neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
    ./geknoei.sh: line 30: ../GRAPHIQUES/20091209_093???.nc: No such file or directory
    , neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
    ./geknoei.sh: line 30: ../GRAPHIQUES/20091209_094350.nc: Permission denied
    , neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
    ./geknoei.sh: line 30: ../GRAPHIQUES/20091209_100257.nc: Permission denied
    , neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
    ./geknoei.sh: line 30: ../GRAPHIQUES/20091209_102229.nc: Permission denied
    , neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
```

It is normal that some files can not be found (no such file or directory).

The path to my script is: `/home/elisev/SYMPHONIE2015/ROC_CONNECT/Scripts`

The path to my files is:`/home/elisev/SYMPHONIE2015/ROC_CONNECT/GRAPHIQUES`

How do I stop these errors from occuring so it can nicely extract what I need?

EDIT: removing the `$()` around `$(../GRAPHIQUES/${Time})` got rid of the permission denied error. Now the error just reads:

```
, neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
, neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
, neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
, neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
, neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
, neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
, neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
, neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
, neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
, neither exists locally nor matches remote filename patterns
```

Comment: You are trying to execute the files in `$(../GRAPHIQUES/${Time})` which is probably not what you want. What happens if you remove `$(` and `)`?

Comment: looks like you are trying to execute/source a non exiting .nc file. (for once `No such file or directory` or `Permission denied` are explicit error messages, one can be confused when unix do so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was the format of the numbers in the files I.txt and J.txt. The needed to be integers (`520` in stead of `5.2000000e+02`)
Once I changed that (by using `dlmwrite('myFile.txt', myMatrix);` in matlab) my code looks like this and works:

```
outputNumber="$(wc -l Time122009.txt)"  #"$(ls -lq *_??????.nc | wc -l)"

echo "the number of lines in the Time text file is ${outputNumber}"

# from all the netcdf files extract the vel_u (and eventually vel_v) with the indices that are in I.txt and J.txt
for ((index=1; index<=10; index++)) #size de I.txt 
do
arrI1=$(sed -n $index'p' I1.txt)
arrI2=$(sed -n $index'p' I2.txt)

arrJ1=$(sed -n $index'p' J1.txt)
arrJ2=$(sed -n $index'p' J2.txt)

Addition=`expr $index + 253` 
Time=$(sed -n $Addition'p' Time122009.txt) #TempsModel.txt
        echo $Addition
        ncrcat -C -F -d nj_u,$arrJ2,$arrJ2 -d ni_u,$arrI1,$arrI2 -v vel_u /home/elisev/SYMPHONIE2015/ROC_CONNECT/GRAPHIQUES/${Time} $index.nc 
        echo "${Time}"
done
```